# Golang not able to detect implicitly typed const when assigning to a variable

Tags: go, types, casting

When I try to assign an implicitly typed constant to a variable, the assigned variable doesn't detect the custom type and instead gets assigned as the underlying primitive type. i.e;
For:

```
type Custom string
const (
    First Custom = "10"
    Second = "20"
)
```

If I have a function:

```
func SomeFunc( x Custom) {
    fmt.Printf("Inside func %v %v", x, reflect.TypeOf(x))
}
```

Then when I:

```
out := Second
SomeFunc(out)
```

it errors with:

> cannot use out (type string) as type Custom in argument to SomeFunc

However `SomeFunc(Second)` works fine.

Also

```
fmt.Printf("%v %v\n",reflect.TypeOf(second),reflect.TypeOf(out)) //prints string string
```

Here is the reproducer: https://play.golang.org/p/Iv-C1ee992

Can someone help me understand what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Second` is an untyped const and has this property (https://blog.golang.org/constants):

> An untyped constant is just a value, one not yet given a defined type
>   that would force it to obey the strict rules that prevent combining
>   differently typed values.
>   ...
>   Assigning them to a variable of any type compatible with strings works
>   without error.

On the contrary `out` is a  variable of type string. Again from the blog post:

> and by now you might be asking, "if the constant is untyped, how does
>   str get a type in this variable declaration?" The answer is that an
>   untyped constant has a default type, an implicit type that it
>   transfers to a value if a type is needed where none is provided. For
>   untyped string constants, that default type is obviously string

Comment: I'll wager the confusion is due to the implicit typing of following constants _if you don't assign them a value_, as in this example: https://play.golang.org/p/0rCHhMN6vv

Comment: @Kaedys Yup that is what confused me.